# Python tags loop

Tags: python

How would you replace these tags with actual data:

```
[|RSSITEMS:]

[|RSSITEM:TITLE|]
[|RSSITEM:CONTENT|]

[|END:RSSITEMS|]
```

[|RSSITEMS:] starts loop at the top and ends its [|END:RSSITEMS|]

[|RSSITEM:TITLE|] and [|RSSITEM:CONTENT|] should be replaced with data from rss feeds.

Feed data is already in database.

Can not use django templates, as HTML above will be different in most cases, can not use templates. the HTML is stored in database.

Comment: -1. This makes no sense. Where are these tags coming from? Why can't you use Django template tags? Where is the data coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use custom templates for RSS. There is a syndication framework:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/

Comment: feed syndication is already in place. just need to replace tags to actual data.

Comment: {% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.title }}
    {{ entry.content }}
    {% endfor %}

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use an existing template engine instead, such as [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/) ([example](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/examples.html)) or [the one from Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/) ([example with for loop](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)).